# Difference between Database.BeginTransaction() and Database.GetTransaction() Using petapoco?

Tags: c#, database, orm, petapoco

```
using (var trn =database.GetTransaction())
{
    database.BeginTransaction();//it is required or not?
    database.Save(Table);
    trn.complete()
}
```

what is use of BeginTransaction() in petapoco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetTransaction()` create a new transaction object, that executes `BeginTransaction()` so there no need to call it.

[image]

[image]

I think the you can use `BeginTransaction()` when you need more granular transaction control. I've never used it independently.